# mod_proxy_wstunnel, sudo a2enmod proxy_wstunnel does not work on centos

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

Hi I am trying to install mod_proxy_wstunnel as instructed in the link http://www.amoss.me.uk/2013/06/apache-2-2-websocket-proxying-ubuntu-mod_proxy_wstunnel/, I am running Centos server. When I run the command

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
```

I get a error

> sudo: a2enmod: command not found.

Could anyone please help me.

Cheers
Sunil

Comment: your link is not available anymore

Answer (score 5):

This module is not listed in `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-proxy.conf`
to be uncommented but that doesn't mean it's not there.
It's available in `/etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so`

Just edit file

```
vi /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-proxy.conf
```

and add this to the end

```
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
```

Restart apache and check

```
service httpd restart
httpd -M | grep wstunnel
```

If you get

```
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
```

You are ready to roll

Answer (score -2):

The a2enmod command is an Ubuntu on Apache construct, which is why you are getting the error. All this command does is symlink the .so module files in mods-available to mods-enabled. These are then loaded automatically by Apache. However, those folders are another Ubuntu on Aapache construct so you won't find them on Centos. Centos uses a modules directory in the /etc/httpd directory that is a symlink to /usr/lib64/httpd/modules (on my system) so you just need.

That said, in order to install mod_proxy_wstunnel you need to have Apache2.4 or better. See the compatability on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html.

Comment: I've Apache 2.4.18. So, How can I enable  the mod_proxy_wstunnel on my system?

Comment: This is supremely unhelpful - how do I actually install it?